# How do I replace multiple newlines with a single one with Perl's Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a document containing empty lines (\n\n). They can be removed with sed:

```
echo $'a\n\nb'|sed -e '/^$/d'
```

But how do I do that with an ordinary regular expression in perl? Anything like the following just shows no result at all.

```
echo $'a\n\nb'|perl -p -e 's/\n\n/\n/s'
```

Comment: If you need it as a filter for shell scripting, like your examples make assume, you'd be faster and more compatible with `cat -s`.

Comment: @Marian Thanks for pointing that out. I just realized I had never read `man cat` until today.

Comment: @Marian I don't need it as input anymore later; But nevertheless, thanks for pointing that out. I may be using that in future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The narrower problem of not printing blank lines is more straightforward:

```
$(input) | perl -ne 'print if /\S/'
```

will output all lines except the ones that only contain whitespace.

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `s/^\n\z//`. Input is read by line so you will never get more than one newline. Instead, eliminate lines that do not contain any other characters. You should invoke `perl` using

```
perl -ne 's/^\n\z//; print'
```

No need for the `/s` switch.

Comment: This is nicer than slurping in the entire file at once, which is not a good idea if the file is really large.

Comment: A slightly different way to do this is `perl -pne 's/^\n\z//'. There is no need for the `print` with the `-p` option.

Answer (score 3):

The input is three separate lines, and `perl` with the `-p` option only processes one line at time.

The workaround is to tell `perl` to slurp in multiple lines of input at once. One way to do it is:

```
echo $'a\n\nb' | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=undef}; s/\n\n/\n/'
```

Here `$/` is the [record separator variable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlvar#$RECORD_SEPARATOR), which tells perl how to parse an input stream into lines.